# how to get or set database error user friendly for user .net core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

I am developing .net core web application with angular and typescript, what I need is to track error in user friendly manner.

```
 public JsonResult Post([FromBody] Data product)
{
  Response.StatusCode = 200;


  try
  {
    repo.Insert(new TblStudentRegisteration() { RgNo = product.rgno , Name = product.name , FatherName = product.FatherName});
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Response.StatusCode = 400;
    return Json(e.ToString());
  }
  return Json("ok");
}
```

Where RGNo is primary key, What I need is whenever any error raised by Database, Error it return in user friendly manner?

Like when user give RgNo two times exception throws like

> "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tbl_StudentRegisteration'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tbl_StudentRegisteration'.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(Tuple`2 parameters)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entries)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
>      at RepositoryData.Repository`1.Insert(T entity) in

Where I understand that this is the problem of duplicate entries, from this given sentence.

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tbl_StudentRegisteration'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tbl_StudentRegisteration'

How User understand this? until and unless we define them in a best way.

is there easiest way to do this?

**EDIT**
One thing I want to clear that, I know there are many ways to do this like, first check whether this RgNo exist, and then post it to DB, but there are also some others excpetion, use of `ex.Message` will give short form, etc, but I want something easier which makes my life easier every time.

Comment: I don't think 400 is the right status to return here but even if you return "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tbl_StudentRegisteration'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tbl_StudentRegisteration'" user won't understand it. You can log the error you receive and return something like "Error saving to the database, try again". If the error is duplicate ID, it's nothing the user can do anyway, you need to fix that in your code/database.

Comment: thanks @artm for pointing out for 400 response, It's not about only duplicate transaction, but also other errors, which will thrown by DB. That's why I am curious, what procedure is best for this?

Comment: Yeah like I said, log the errors with a logger (NLog for example) and return a simple string to the user. Then you can check the log (text file or database) for error details.

Comment: You could define your own Exception classes with messages that you want, and then the certain exception raised, throw your own exception with setting raised exception as `inner exception`. Writing to log will be additional help to investigate what was happend.

Comment: I would say two things: 1) if possible, don't let the user supply the primary key. That way, you won't run into this issue and won't have to create a useful error message for it. 2) The error return code should be 500, as it is an error on the server.